# Stop video playing in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uiwebview

I have played video in UIWebView.

I have use this code

```
 NSString *Str = @"<video controls width=458 height=202 poster=Image.png> 
                   <source   src=\"http://Path of the video/Video.mp4\"> </video>";

 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Image"
                  ofType:@"png"];
 [web loadHTMLString:Str baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

Can i stop the pause or stop the video without tap on pause button?

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can stop video like:-

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [YourWebView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    }
```